# How to apply regex based replacements in array of strings in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have some MongoDB documents in this structure:

```
{
"name":"Bob",
"tags":["foo","bar"]
}
```

```
{
"name":"John",
"tags":["foo","bar,"]
}
```

```
{
"name":"Angela",
"tags":["foo,"]
}
```

Due to a data migration gone wrong some of the tags contain commas in their string values e.g. `foo,` not `foo`

I can identify these documents using `db.collections.find({tags:/,/})`. But how can I update them to strip out the commas, so for example I'd end up with:

```
{
"name":"John",
"tags":["foo","bar"]
}
```

Comment: What is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collections.find({tags:/,/}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.tags = doc.tags.map(x => x.replace(/,/g, ""));    
    db.collections.save(doc);
})
```